# A word that describes the act of standing on foot to venerate someone

Tags: word-choice

In some cultures like that of mine, people revere the elderly, teachers, judges, or other respected people by standing on foot when they enter the room they are sitting in. What is the word that represents this action?

Comment: *Standing on foot* is a very strange expression—one that I've never heard used. If taken literally, *standing on foot* would mean *standing on **one** foot*. I assume you mean to just say *standing*.

Comment: They rose to their feet // He rose [to his feet] when the ambassador was introduced...

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two common expressions used when asking people to stand up as a sign of respect: **"[all rise](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/all-rise)"**, and, **"[be upstanding](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-upstanding)"**. However, their use is limited to specific situations.

When a judge is entering or leaving a court, or when sentence is being passed, a court official will say:

> All rise!

When a respected dignatory is entering a venue, or when an anthem or flag is being honoured, someone might say, for example:

> Please be upstanding for the national anthem

In a military inspection, a soldier will be ask asked to **"Stand to attention"**.

However, there is no common English word or expression that covers all situations where one stands as a mark of respect, and only those situations. The best way to explain the cultural tradition you described is probably exactly that:

> When a respected person enters the room we **stand as a mark of respect**

**EDIT**

I don't think there is an a word or phrase already in the English language for exactly the tradition that the question descibes. That's because because it has never been part of the culture of any English-speaking country. For example, it is not normal to stand up when one's grandfather enters the room.

In general, these kinds of culture-specific behaviours are given an English name based on the words from the source culture. For example, the Chinese practice of prostrating before the Emperor is called ***kowtowing*** in English, from the Chinese word ***kētóu***. If you are explaining a practice from your own culture that doesn't have a name in English, you could just use the name for it in your language, with an explanation.

> When Grandfather comes into the room, we ______________ which means standing up to show respect.

Comment: In some cases, I find "all rise" closer to what we do. In our schools, when teacher comes in, somebody says "all rise". Standing up, when there is no announcement, is what I like to find a description for.

Comment: @DavoodFalahati I understand. Please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Did "be upstanding" start out as a sort of joke alternative to "stand up", given what "upstanding" means?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no word that represents exactly what you're asking.

[Honor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honor) can mean "to regard or treat (someone) with admiration and respect : to regard or treat with honor".  So you can use "stand to honor" or "rise to honor", stating that they are doing so as a sign of respect.

I think that is about as close as we can get.